# Upgrade from AEM 6.0 to 6.1 Dispatcher 4.1.9 issues

Tags: aem, dispatcher

We are trying to upgrade to AEM 6.1 from 6.0sp2. As Adobe suggested that we have to upgrade the Dispatcher to 4.1.9 (as mentioned here https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes.html )

On Publish instance, we did the following:

1. Downloaded the new dispatcher file from https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/companies/public/adobe/dispatcher/dispatcher/_jcr_content/top/download_37/file.res/dispatcher-apache2.2-windows-x86-4.1.9.zip
2. Replaced the "disp_apache2.2" file in C:\Apache2\modules. We did not change any settings "dispatcher.any"  as we wanted all of them to work as they were working.
3. Restarted Apache, then AEM.

But the site is not loading, not even localhost http://localhost:4503 (Publish instance)

We can see the following errors in "startup" log file:

```
27.07.2015 14:39:37.890 *ERROR* [main] ERROR: Unable to re-install   slinginstall:E:\aem\publish2\crx-quickstart\launchpad\startup\1\org.apache.sling.fragment.ws-1.0.2.jar(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0)java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

The path "E:\aem\publish2.." did not exist. The one we had was "E:\aem\publish.."

Did anyone come across similar? Or are we missing any step?

Comment: By http://localhost:4503 , I assume your publish instance itself is not loading correctly. I don't think dispatcher is the culprit. Can you spin a fresh AEM 6.1 publish instance and check if the dispatcher is delegating the requests to publish ?

Comment: Yes, by 4503, i meant Publish instance. I will try and update the posting.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue is not related to Dispatcher upgrade, but is related to AEM not able to connect to an external device where the content is being stored.

After we resolved the issues, the upgrade went on smoothly.